# How do I check bathroom plumbing vent?

Tags: bathroom, venting

I have an addition where the toilet clogs every few weeks. You can hear it coming a few flushes before the back up with a LOT of gurgling in the pipes. I "fix it" by running the shower, and air is forced up and out of the toilet, and then a few minutes later the toilet drains and is unclogged.

After snooping here, I suspect something is improperly vented. But where do I find the vents? Are there separate vents for toilet and shower?

Comment: Guessing this is a house.  The plumbing vent/s usually go though the roof, and can become clogged.  Usually there is one main vent close for toilets/sinks/showers, but if there is more plumbing at the other end of the house, might be a second vent.  Try to find a clean out(a tee with a cap) and can probably run a snake up the vent.

Comment: Welcome. Whether you're "out of your league" or not is subjective and not for us to decide. I've removed that part of your post as off-topic.

Comment: Dupe : [Does my toilet drain poorly because of bad venting?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/204078/41369)  TLDR;  No.  Venting problems cannot cause slow drains.  This is a very common misconception.  You have a blockage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your vent, if it exists, should reach the roof (there are exceptions, as noted in comments). You can look at the roof for a short metal or plastic pipe sticking out, it may or may not have a cap. This would give you a rough idea where it is inside the house, it is likely inside a wall. Depending on the layout there may be more than one vent.

If it does not have a cap it could be plugged by something (birds, squirrels, intercontinental coconuts) falling into it - this would likely be apparent with more plumbing issues (gurgling, slow draining) at more than just your toilet, though - if there is more than one vent it could affect "half the sinks/toilets" or be limited to "just one bathroom's devices".

If you can find the vent and find a clean-out as suggested in a comment, you can try to clean it out. Have a bucket under the cleanout in case "stuff" comes out as you're working.

[image]

Comment: Note that there could be more than one plumbing vent based on the layout of fixtures in the house.

Comment: This might [once more] depend on territory, but vents don't need to go above roof height any more, so long as they have a one-way valve. That means it could be in loft space, or just truncated on an outside wall.

Comment: Ewww... @Tetsujin. They allow venting sewer gas into the attic in your neck of the woods?

Comment: It doesn't vent, it's a one-way valve, air input only. https://www.drainagepipe.co.uk/soil-and-waste/how-to-use-an-air-admittance-valve/

Comment: Ask yourself this - If the air vent is plugged, what is stopping air from entering the system from the big open toilet bowl?  (hint : nothing)  So the water will still go down with a blocked vent.  Sometimes even faster - and it'll take the trap water with it because that's where the air is coming from.  Plugged vents don't cause slow drains.  Blockages do.